# first centroid on k-means algorithm should be "random"?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

In the case of k-means.

If 2 initial data sets become centroid value then it will produce cluster 1 and cluster 2 generate value 0 ... why?

Is not this a strange thing?

Measure the distance of the centroid to the distance itself?

Like measuring the distance from america to america itself ...
is there an explanation of the steps in the k-mean algorithm.
Especially in the phrase "in determining the value of the centroid, the initial value of the centroid is done randomly".

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please proofread your postings. And try to be specific. What exactly is your question? Where have you searched, where exactly are you stuck? Please also take into account, that SO is about coding and consider asking rather here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Usually all initial centroids are random (today we often use clever random techniques such as k-means++).

Initializing all centroids with the global mean is *bad*. Never do this!
Because obviously every point will have the same distance to each center. Then usually all points will be assigned to the first cluster (which then will not move), and all the others will be empty. This is the ***worst* possible initialization** (for quality, not for runtime)!